# usb directories and files changing their permission

Tags: usb, permissions, read-only

Here is the problem, I insert my USB key, and it opens automatically, nothing looks locked. directories and files look totally fine. I try to move them to my computer using "sudo mv" command even though they are moved in terminal i get the message that it is not possible to move the specified directory cuz it's read only. I tried changing the permission using "chmod" but still have the problem and it is driving me mad. would you please help me with this?
Here is an important question, should I change the permission of the mountpoint or the permission of the /dev/sdb1 (partition) or the permission of /dev/sdb (the whole drive)? 
cheers

Comment: The copy works? mv is trying to move the file, so, try to copy the files first. Then, try to format the USB with gparted or something similar.

Comment: I've had an issue like this with an SD card before when there was a slider on the side for "locking" the card and making it read-only. There could be an equivalent issue here with your USB. If not, then try and see if you can edit the files on the USB from another computer. If you can, then you know it's an issue with the original computer, but if you can't, then you know if it's an issue with the USB.

Comment: Why are you using sudo for a simple copy/move operation? It isn't required and most likely it's what's causing the issues. Also permissions is something you need to consider when dealing with EXT partitions and unless you explicitly formated it as such the default in USB drives is FAT32 (exFAT for +64GB).

Comment: Well thanks for your answers. I used both mv and copy the problem remains the same, it is also ironic because first when i insert the usb key directories are fine without any lock icon on them, when I try to manipulate them such as copying or moving they become locked. although I don't have a slider on my usb key to lock it or unlock it, but you are right that's a problem only with my laptop not with a desktop that I use.
I am not only using sudo, it is one of the options that I considered and it doesn't change much of my problem